# How come the limit does not exist for $\lim_{x\to8}\frac{x^2-64}{|x-8|}$ with absolute value in the denominator?

Tags: calculus, limits

Came across this question, for which I thought the limit should have been 16. Turns out it did not exist. I don't understand why:
$$\lim_{x\to8}\frac{x^2-64}{|x-8|}$$

Comment: Hint: look at the one-sided limits.

Comment: Consider from lhs and rhs of 8 and see the mod

Comment: Because its positive 16 when approaching from above and negative when approaching from below.

Comment: Hint if $x\ne 8$ $(x^2-64)/(x-8) = x+8$ while $(x^2-64)/-(x-8)=-(x+8) $

Comment: ohh I got it now. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

$$\lim_{x\to8}\frac{x^2-64}{|x-8|}=\lim_{x\to8}\frac{(x-8)(x+8)}{|x-8|}$$

**If $x>8$** then $x-8>0$ and $|x-8|=x-8$ so 
$$\lim_{x\to8^{+}}\frac{x^2-64}{|x-8|}=\lim_{x\to8^{+}}\frac{(x-8)(x+8)}{x-8}=16$$
**If $x<8$** then $x-8<0$ and $|x-8|=-(x-8)$ so 
$$\lim_{x\to8^{-}}\frac{x^2-64}{|x-8|}=\lim_{x\to8^{-}}\frac{(x-8)(x+8)}{-(x-8)}=-16$$

Comment: @John_Smith Thanks.

Comment: This part, although I understand what you mean, seems a little contradictory to me: |x - 8| = -(x - 8)  ;  isn't the stuff inside the parentheses evaluated first, then the absolute value operation applied? That should result in an always positive number the way I see it, 2hich is why I find that minus sign a little confusing

Comment: -(x-8) *is* a positive number if x <8.  x-8 <0 so -(x-8) >0.  And |x-8|=-(x-8).  Or put another way x-8 < 0 so |x-8|= opposite value (x-8)=-(x-8).  You aren't the first to find it confusing.

Answer (score 2):

When you see,

$$\frac{(x-8)}{|x-8|}$$

We cannot reduce this to $1$, if $x<8$ then we have $|x-8|=-(x-8)$ so then the fraction reduces to $-1$. I hope this helps you  understand why the limit does not exist. From one direction the limit goes to $16(-1)$ and the other $16(1)$.

Answer (score 1):

I'll add to the other answers that have been given.  Graph the function on the interval $(7, 9)$ using a graphing calculator or WolframAlpha.com.  You'll see from the graph that that the limit does not exist.